# How do I export categories, site stats, comments and posts from wordpress to excel

Tags: taxonomy, plugin-recommendation, export, csv, google-analytics

I need to export the posts, categories, the author, the page views and comments from WordPress to excel. This is because I need to analyze the performance of each author and each category based on page views and comments. I tried the WP all Export plugin but it was not compatible with the site. How can I go about achieving this. It is quite urgent and I need help

Comment: You don't need WordPress for that. Just use MySQL's `INTO OUTFILE` to [create a CSV](https://michaelrigart.be/export-directly-mysql-csv/) that can be read by Excel.

Comment: WordPress importer/Exporter. It's a plugin. Install, activate, export, done.